# How to convert negative time span to positive in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, timestamp, timespan

I have a situation in which some time duration is in negative format and stored as string in SQL database as

```
-06:34:41
```

and some of will be in positive format  as

`02:00:00` and

```
01:00:00
```

Now I need to add/sum these time duration in select query using SQL Server 2008 such that result will be

```
-03:34:41
```

and then after calculation i need it back into string format .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert string to `TIME` data type and multiply by -1

Comment: @Raj Will you kindly create a sample query for  me i did that but give me error that "Operand type clash: time is incompatible with int"

Comment: which time format is this? hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @CeOnSql, Yeah hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Raj - that would not be suitable. The `time` data type represents a *time of day*, not a *time span*. As such, it doesn't allow negative values, nor values greater than 24 hours, nor does it support addition or subtraction, since none of those things make *sense* for a time of day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
declare @timevalues table
(
    timestring NVARCHAR(10)
)

insert into @timevalues
values
 ('-06:34:41'),
 ('02:00:00'),
 ('01:00:00')
;

with cte
as
( select    case when left(timestring,1)='-' then -1 else 1 end as multiply,
            right(timestring,8) as timestring,
            --get hours in seconds:
            DATEPART(HOUR,right(timestring,8)) * 3600 AS h_in_s,
            --get minutes in seconds:
            DATEPART(MINUTE,right(timestring,8)) * 60 AS m_in_s,
            --get seconds:
            DATEPART(SECOND,right(timestring,8)) AS s
  from      @timevalues 
)

select  case when sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply) < 0
            then '-' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,ABS(sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply)),0),114)
            else CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply),0),114)
        end as new_time_string
from    cte c
```

Output is:

[image: output]

what this basically does: in the cte i put all time components to seconds, so we can sum up seconds (`h_in_s + m_in_s + s`). after you got the sum of seconds you need to transform seconds to a time string. this is done by adding 0 seconds to our expression (e.g. `DATEADD(s,15300,0)`). converting this to varchar with format code 114 and voilà

Comment: Your are Awesome . It works fine for fix values that i mentioned. So if i want to get these values from SQL table e-g tblAttend and column name ExtraHrs then how to edit this script.